# Facilitated Swiss citizenship for Non-Eu citizens

Tags: citizenship, switzerland

I'm curious about the facilitated Swiss citizenship process for a **Non-EU** citizen, but **without being in registered partnership nor marriage with a Swiss citizen**. As a side-note, the job that person would work would be a high paying job in the IT industry.

There is this 'Article 22' that I found [here](https://www.admin.ch/opc/de/classified-compilation/20092990/index.html#a22), where it says the following:

> Anyone who has lived in good faith for five years and has Swiss citizenship, and during which time has actually been treated as Swiss by cantonal or municipal authorities, can apply for easier naturalization.

What does 'good faith' mean and how can someone determine if a person 'has been treated as a Swiss by cantonal and municipal authorities'? Also, does that mean living for 5 years on a C-permit?

A few more paragraphs can be found [here](https://www.sem.admin.ch/dam/data/sem/rechtsgrundlagen/weisungen/buergerrecht/hb-bueg18-kap6-d.pdf) under the 'Irrtümlich angenommenes Schweizer Bürgerrecht' chapter.

I know many of these things vary between cantons, but I just wanted to make more sense by asking here as I'm not a native German speaker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> guten Glauben gelebt hat, das Schweizer Bürgerrecht zu besitzen

The translation should be understood as: *in good faith **believes** to be a Swiss citizen*.

---

Possible situation:

When a parent is naturalized, the minor children are often also naturalized.

For some reason, the naturalization took place on (or after) the day the child became an adult (thus was not a minor).

Nobody noticed this at the time and the child recieved an ID and passport from the Canton or local authority and the child performed their national duty as a Swiss citizen.

6 years later, this mistake is noticed.

Since the person **believed** that they had been naturalized with their parents **and** had been treated as a Swiss citizen by the Swiss authorities, **[Article 22](https://www.admin.ch/opc/de/classified-compilation/20092990/index.html#a22)** (simplifed naturalization) applies to correct this situation.

---

> **[Article 22](https://www.admin.ch/opc/de/classified-compilation/20092990/index.html#a22)**
> 1 Wer während fünf Jahren im **guten Glauben gelebt hat, das Schweizer Bürgerrecht zu besitzen**, und während dieser Zeit von kantonalen oder Gemeindebehörden tatsächlich als Schweizerin oder als Schweizer behandelt worden ist, kann ein Gesuch um erleichterte Einbürgerung stellen.
>
> 2 Die eingebürgerte Person erhält das Kantonsbürgerrecht des für den Irrtum verantwortlichen Kantons. Dieser bestimmt, welches Gemeindebürgerrecht gleichzeitig erworben wird.

---

**Sources**:

- [SR 141.0 Bundesgesetz vom 20. Juni 2014 über das Schweizer Bürgerrecht (Bürgerrechtsgesetz, BüG)](https://www.admin.ch/opc/de/classified-compilation/20092990/index.html#a22)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In other words, according to your proposed interpretation, this has nothing to do with being able to get a citizenship as a Non-EU expat that worked in Switzerland after 5 years on, say, residence permit?

Comment: @birdybird03 Yes, this is a *correction* section for a special situation of mistaken assumption of swiss citizenship. A C-permit is applied for by a foreigner to a foreigner, so there is no doubt that the applicant is not a swiss citizen by anybody.

Comment: @birdybird03 Your second link (implementation details), contained the condition: documents were issued by the authorities (like a swiss ID or passport) stating that the person is a Swiss citizen. This is not the case for a C-permit.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification Mark.